# How to organise Function Maps for specific endpoints in Gin (GoLang)?

Tags: function, go, templates, view, content-management-system

### TL;DR

I'm wondering how to organise function maps for go templates that are dependant on the data being obtained in the specific endpoint being called.

### Issue

I have a main frontend endpoint (for a CMS) which will grab the slug of the page, and go and obtain the post data it from the model. I also have a templates package that takes in models, the post data and gin context.
GoView is currently being used. But I am setting **HTMLRender to equal a new ginview evertime the page is hit** presumably this isn't great for performance and I'm wondering if there is a neater way of going about it.

```
// Serve the front end website
func (c *FrontendController) Serve(g *gin.Context) {
    path := g.Request.URL.Path
    post, err := c.models.Posts.GetBySlug(path)

    if err != nil {
        NoPageFound(g)
        return
    }

    tf := templates.NewFunctions(g, c.models, &post)
    c.server.HTMLRender = ginview.New(goview.Config{
        Root:      paths.Theme(),
        Extension: config.Template["file_extension"],
        Master:    "/layouts/main",
        Partials:  []string{},
        DisableCache: true,
        Funcs: tf.GetFunctions(),
    })

    r := ResourceData{
        Post: post,
    }

    g.HTML(200, config.Template["template_dir"] + "/" + post.PageTemplate, r)
}
```

### Templates

Some template functions include getting the field & author of the post, and seeing if the user is logged in, for example.

```
func (t *TemplateFunctions) isAuth() bool {
   ...
}
```

There are also template functions that aren't tied to `gin.context` such as getting the assets path.

```
func (t *TemplateFunctions) assetsPath() string {
    ...
}
```

### Questions

- Is there a way to merge the data dependant functions with global ones?
- Is there a way to set the template functions without redeclaring the HTMLRender every time a page is hit? Or is it necessary?